# C++ Pimpl Idiom using a pre-existing class

Tags: c++, c++11

We have a heavily-templated header-only codebase that a client would like access to. For example, let's say it contains the `Foo` class in the header `foo.hpp`:

```
#ifndef FOO_HEADER
#define FOO_HEADER

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Foo {

    Foo(){
       // Do a bunch of expensive initialization
    }

    void bar(T t){
        std::cout << t; 
    }

    // Members to initialize go here... 
};

#endif /* FOO_HEADER */
```

Now we want to let the client try a reduced set of the functionality without exposing the core code and without rewriting the whole codebase.

One idea would be to use the PIMPL idiom to wrap this core code. Specifically, we could create a `FooWrapper` class with the header `foo_wrapper.hpp`:

```
#ifndef FOO_WRAPPER_HEADER
#define FOO_WRAPPER_HEADER

#include <memory>

struct FooWrapper {

    FooWrapper();
    ~FooWrapper();

    void bar(double t);

    private: 
        struct Impl;
        std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;
};

#endif /* FOO_WRAPPER_HEADER */
```

and implementation `foo_wrapper.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.hpp"
#include "foo_wrapper.hpp"

struct FooWrapper::Impl {
    Foo<double> genie;
};

void FooWrapper::bar(double t){
    impl->genie.bar(t);
}

FooWrapper::FooWrapper() : impl(new Impl){
}

FooWrapper::~FooWrapper() = default;
```

This code works as I expect it: https://wandbox.org/permlink/gso7mbe0UEOOPG7j

However, there is one little nagging thing that is bothering me. Specifically, the implementation requires what feels like an additional level of indirection... We have to define the `Impl` class to hold a member of the `Foo` class. Because of this, all of the operations have this indirection of the form `impl->genie.bar(t);`.

It would be better if we could somehow tell the compiler, "Actually `Impl` IS the class `Foo<double>`", in which case, we could instead say `impl->bar(t);`.

Specifically, I am thinking something along the lines of `typedef` or `using` to get this to work. Something like

```
using FooWrapper::Impl = Foo<double>;
```

But this does not compile. So on to the questions:

1. Is there a nice way to get rid of this indirection?
2. Is there a better idiom I should be using?

I am targeting a C++11 solution, but C++14 may work as well. The important thing to remember is that the solution can't use the header `foo.hpp` in `foo_wrapper.hpp`. Somehow we have to compile that code into a library and distribute just the compiled library and the `foo_wrapper` header.

Comment: Are you worrying about the runtime cost of the indirection or about the syntactic "overhead"?

Comment: Just the syntactic overhead. I'm not so sure that there be any significant runtime overhead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just forward-declare `Foo` in `FooWrapper.h`. This will allow you to declare a `std::unique_ptr` for it:

```
#ifndef FOO_WRAPPER_HEADER
#define FOO_WRAPPER_HEADER

#include <memory>

// Forward declaration
template <typename T>
class Foo;

struct FooWrapper {
  FooWrapper();
  ~FooWrapper();

  void bar(double t);

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<Foo<double>> impl;
};

#endif /* FOO_WRAPPER_HEADER */
```

`foo_wrapper.cc`:

```
#include "foo_wrapper.h"
#include "foo.h"

void FooWrapper::bar(double t) {
  impl->bar(t);
}

FooWrapper::FooWrapper() : impl(std::make_unique<Foo<double>>()) {}

FooWrapper::~FooWrapper() = default;
```

Comment: You can just do `std::unique_ptr<Foo<double>> impl;` directly. No need to introduce a `using` alias and no need for a manual template instantiation. The ctor implementation can then just do `FooWrapper::FooWrapper() : impl(std::make_unique<Foo<double>>()) {}`

Comment: @NikosC. whoops, right. Had a "bug" in my test code

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Foo<double>`:

```
// forward declaration so that you don't need to include "Foo.hpp"
template class Foo<double>;

struct FooWrapper {
    //...
    std::unique_ptr<Foo<double>> impl;
};
```

```
// explicit template instantiation so that Foo<double> exists without distributing "Foo.hpp"
template class Foo<double>;

void FooWrapper::bar(double t){
    impl->bar(t);
}
```

Comment: This would require giving the client the `foo.hpp` code. We don't want to do that because that contains the proprietary code.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, your `foo_wrapper.hpp` code would have to import `foo.hpp`, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Conversely, in the version I propose, we only have to give the client `foo_wrapper.hpp` and a library compiled from `foo_wrapper.cpp`. This protects the proprietary code to some extent (assuming that they will not decompile the code)